# Div pushes down other div, CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add simple sidebar to existing layout (content).

So far I have like this.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="side-menui">

        </div>

   ....
</div>
```

Full HTML

```
 <div class="container">


      <div class="side-menui">

        </div>



      <div class="banner-navigation-containet clearfix">
        <div class="navigation-container pull-left">
          <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
              <div class="container-fluid clearfix">
                <div class="navbar-header pull-left">                   
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv">
                      <img alt="logo" class="img-responsive" src="./Ind_files/logo.png" title="logo">  


                    </a>
                </div>






                <div class="selections">

                <div class="pull-left">

                      <a aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1#">LATVIJA</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                       <a href="http://www..eu/lv?country_id=2">IGAUNIJA</a>
                      </ul>
                  </div>


                <div class="pull-right">
                <a aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1#" id="dropdownMenu2">LV</a>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                               <li><a href="http://www.lo.eu/ru">RU</a></li>



                     </ul>

                    </div>

              </div><!-- End language-container -->



              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
          </nav><!-- End navbar-->
        </div><!--End navigation-container-->

        <div class="banner-2 pull-left">                      

           <img alt="Selection 011" class="img-responsive" height="90" id="banner" src="./Ind_files/Selection_011.jpg" width="500">




        </div>



        <div class="banner-3 pull-left" ;="">

             <img alt="Selection 011" class="img-responsive" height="90" id="banner2" src="./Ind_files/Selection_011(1).jpg" width="500">


        </div>



      </div><!-- End banner-navigation-containet -->





   <!--<div id="bag-icon" class="flip2"> <img alt="Bag icon" src="/assets/bag-icon.png" /></div> 

        <div id="nav-toggle-lines" class="flip"></div> -->





      <div class="row block-list">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 block clearfix" id="advertisement-col" style="display:none; border:none;">

          </div><!-- End block-->


          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 block clearfix">
            <div class="block-main-info clearfix">
              <div class="pull-left block-main-title">dasdad</div>
              <div class="pull-left block-main-location">Buļļi</div>
              <div class="pull-left block-main-id">ID </div>
            </div><!-- End block-main-info -->

            <div class="pull-left block-image">
                   <a class="" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1#" onclick="loginModalShow();" require_login="true"><img alt="dasdad" src="./Ind_files/block-2-image(1).jpg" title="dasdad"></a> 



            </div><!-- End block-image -->

            <div class="pull-left block-info">
              <table>
                <tbody><tr class="block-age">
                  <td class="block-info-image"></td>
                  <td class="block-info-number">22</td>
                  <td class="block-info-text">teksts</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="block-length">
                  <td class="block-info-image"></td>
                  <td class="block-info-number">148</td>
                  <td class="block-info-text">teksts</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="block-weight">
                  <td class="block-info-image"></td>
                  <td class="block-info-number">43</td>
                  <td class="block-info-text">teksts</td>
                </tr>
                   <tr class="block-bust">
                  <td class="block-info-image"></td>
                  <td class="block-info-number">1</td>
                  <td class="block-info-text">teksts</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody></table>

              <div class="block-bottom-info">
                <div class="block-info-tel-number"><span>+371</span> 26262626</div>
                <div class="clearfix">

                  <div class="pull-left">stunda:</div>
                  <div class="pull-right"><b>60</b>EUR</div>
                </div>  
              </div><!-- End  block-info -->
            </div><!-- End block-info -->

          </div><!-- End block-->




        </div><!-- End row-->



      <div class="panel">



         <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://www.lo.eu/lv/girls" class="girl_search" data-remote="true" id="girl_search" method="get"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
                <div class="sort-links">
                    <div class="input-group">

                       <input class="form-control" id="q_name_or_phone_number_or_identifier_cont" name="q[name_or_phone_number_or_identifier_cont]" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
                      <div class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><img alt="Search icon" src="./Ind_files/search-icon.png" width="15"></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <div id="sorter">

             <div id="left">   
                  <select id="q_region_id_eq" name="q[region_id_eq]"><option value="">RAJONS</option>

             </div>

              <div id="center">

                  <a class="sort_link " data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1&q%5Bs%5D=height+asc">AUGUMS</a>
              </div>                
               <div id="right">                                                         

                   <a class="sort_link " data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1&q%5Bs%5D=bust_size+asc">KRŪTIS</a>                    
               </div>   
       </div>

                          <div id="sorter">

                              <div id="left"> 



                                 <a class="sort_link " data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1&q%5Bs%5D=age+asc">VECUMS</a>
                             </div>

                              <div id="center">


                                     <a class="sort_link " data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1&q%5Bs%5D=per_hour+asc">CENA</a>


                             </div>
                               <div id="right"> 



                               <a class="sort_link " data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1&q%5Bs%5D=votes_for.size+asc">REITINGS</a>

                              </div>
                         </div>









                <div class="clickable">

                   <a href="http://www.lo.eu/lv/girls">MEITENES</a>

                  <span>MEITENES</span>

                </div>

                <div class="clickable" id="blacklist-menu">
                   <a href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1#">MELNAIS SARAKSTS</a>

                    <span>MELNAIS SARAKSTS
                     <div class="pull-right">
                       <div id="icon-side"> &gt;
                    <!--- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> -->
                      </div> 
                        <div id="icon-down" style="display:none;"> 
                          <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> -->
                        </div>
                     </div>


                    </span>
                </div>

                    <!--   Noslēptās izvēles -->
                        <div class="clickable" id="hiden" style="display:none;">
                           <a class="" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1#" onclick="loginModalShow();" require_login="true">Meitenes </a>

                          <span>MEITENES</span>

                        </div>
                        <div class="clickable" id="hiden2" style="display:none;">
                           <a class="" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1#" onclick="loginModalShow();" require_login="true">Klienti </a>

                          <span>KLIENTI</span>

                        </div>
                         <!--   Noslēptās izvēles BEIGAS-->

                <div class="clickable" id="shown">
                   <a href="http://www.lo.eu/lv/rules">NOTEIKUMI </a>

                  <span>NOTEIKUMI</span>

                </div>

                <div class="clickable" id="shown2">
                   <a href="http://www.lo.eu/lv/girls/new">IESNIEGT SLUDINĀJUMU </a>

                    <span>IESNIEGT SLUDINĀJUMU</span>
                </div>


</form>


      </div>
        <div class="panel2">





                                <div class="dr">
                         <div class="clickable2">
                             <a class="" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1#" onclick="loginModalShow();" require_login="true">IENĀKT</a>                  
                                 <span>Ieiet</span> 


                        </div>
                        <div class="clickable2">
                        <a href="http://www.lo.eu/lv">ANKETA</a>  

                                 <span>Anketa</span> 


                        </div>

                        <div class="clickable2">

                              <a data-target="#usersignup" data-toggle="modal" href="http://www.lo.eu/lv?country_id=1#" id="asaa">REĢISTRĒTIES</a>                
                                 <span>Reģistrēties</span> 

                        </div>

                        <div class="clickable2">
                             <a href="http://www.lo.eu/lv/help">PALĪDZĪBA</a>                  
                                 <span>Palīdzība</span> 

                        </div>



                  </div><!-- End block-->



      </div>








    </div><!-- End container -->
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 1170px;
    padding: 0;
    }
div.side-menui {
    position: relative;
    left:-20px;
    z-index: 5;
    width:35px;
    height:350px;
    border:1px solid gray;
  }
```

Problem: side-menui pushes down all content exactly his height.

What I need: [image]

I googled for similar questions tried other positions like absolute, fixed .. but I got way worse results than I have already.

I am missing something very straightforward ?

Comment: You may need to float the element like `float:left`

Comment: can you provide your full html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to take the element out of flow so that it isnt going to effect anything else.

you can do this by either setting

`float: left;`

or

`position: absolute; /* or fixed */`

Comment: Thanks, but now my side-menui is on far left. And  resizing screen makes it worse..